# Backslash vs. Forward slash in Java

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt

Why does there need to be a forward slash in the path to the class file when using Windows Command Prompt?

Input:

> `C:\javafun>java --module-path C:\javafun\mod --module jdojo.intro/com.jdojo.intro.Welcome`

Output:

> `Welcome to Java 17!`

I've read that when running .jar files there needs to be a forward slash, but I've created a modular .jar file in `C:\javafun\lib` directory. Here I am just trying to go straight to the .class file in the `C:\javafun\mod\jdojo.intro\com\jdojo\intro\Welcome.class`

Why when I change the below to a backslash when using Windows I get the following error? This is confusing to know when to use specific slashes when dealing with file locations, packages or directories.

Input:

> `C:\javafun>java --module-path C:\javafun\mod --module jdojo.intro\com.jdojo.intro.Welcome`

Output:

> `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer`
> `java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdojo.intro\com.jdojo.intro.Welcome not found`

Comment: The argument to `--module` is a module name with an optional slash-separated main class name, not a native path. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm); it's a `/` whatever platform you're on, as with a URL.

Comment: Here's a thought: perhaps we should change the division operator to "\" for programs running on Windows. For consistency with filepaths :-)

Comment: I now see the forward slash is part of the java command syntax. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, *file paths* need to use the backslash as a separator.  However, this is *not* a file path:

```
--module jdojo.intro\com.jdojo.intro.Welcome
```

The forward slash is a designated separator, on all platforms, between the module name and the class name.

The fact that, on non-Windows systems, file paths happen to use the forward slash character as a directory separator, but it’s a different character in Windows, does not mean that all non-file uses of the forward slash will also be different on Windows.

In fact, [the documentation for the java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) explicitly states that the character between the module name and the class name must be a forward slash:

> To launch the main class in a module:
>
> `java` [*options*] `-m` *module*[`/`*mainclass*] [args ...]
>
> or
>
> `java` [*options*] `--module` *module*[`/`*mainclass*] [*args* ...]

No matter what platform you’re running on, the character between a module name and a class name is a forward slash, because it’s not a file name and therefore is not platform dependent.